# How to create a machine name for custom table field with transliteration available

Tags: uri

I think the title is pretty explanatory.
I have a custom table in which i retrieve human readable titles in 'title'. This title could be any language, and since i'm french it could have accents for instance.
I would like to change a title like : "**L'océan indien, l'Asie et la végétation**" into the 'cleanurl' field : "**l-ocean-indien-l-asie-et-la-vegetation**".

I've seen [this topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13254/how-do-i-create-a-machine-name-type-of-field) that seemed interesting, but neither [machine name](https://www.drupal.org/project/machine_name) nor [safeword](https://www.drupal.org/project/safeword) seems to be usable with transliterate (or i don't see how).

I've tried some "custom" function but does not work completely as expected (and is not a serious replacement for transliterate i guess :

```
function clean_name($string)
{
  $string = html_entity_decode($string);
  $string = str_replace('&#039;', '\'', trim(strtolower($string)));
  $search  = 'àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ';
  $replace = 'aaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy';
  $string = strtr($string, $search, $replace);
  $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $string);
  $string = trim($string, '-');
  $string = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $string);
  return $string;
}
```

What can you suggest to achieve this goal ? I would obviously prefer to use core functions if possible.

EDIT --
@Clive
I tried to use the pathauto/transliteration modules and i've manage to get what i want, but i'm not sure this is the right way.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto', 'pathauto');
module_load_include('module', 'transliteration', 'transliteration');
$cleantitle = pathauto_cleanstring(transliteration_get($string));
```

This might not be the optimal way since as you emphasised : Process the string through the transliteration module, but i'm not at ease enough with Drupal code.
From the code in pathauto_cleanstring(), transliteration_get should be processed automatically if

```
variable_get('pathauto_transliterate', FALSE) && module_exists('transliteration')
```

Both are enabled in my Drupal, but if i do 
`pathauto_cleanstring($string);` the transliteration is not aplied.

But again, if nobody tells me why, this works with `pathauto_cleanstring(transliteration_get($string));`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think core has any such function, but the [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) does.

[`pathauto_cleanstring()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21pathauto%21pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_cleanstring/7):

> Clean up a string segment to be used in an URL alias.
>
> Performs the following possible alterations:
>
> - Remove all HTML tags.
> - **Process the string through the transliteration module.**
> - Replace or remove punctuation with the separator character.
> - Remove back-slashes.
> - Replace non-ascii and non-numeric characters with the separator.
> - Remove common words.
> - Replace whitespace with the separator character.
> - Trim duplicate, leading, and trailing separators.
> - Convert to lower-case.
> - Shorten to a desired length and logical position based on word boundaries.

Emphasis mine.